Calculate with two QSliders values using PyQt5
i am learning to use PyQt5 and one function that can be useful to me is sliders/dials value that i can calculate with an other (for example, i am working on a python app to calculate coil inductance).
But all the tutorials i've found that far online, are simple codes to display on a label.
Generally it looks like this :
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QSlider, QLabel
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI,self).__init__()

        # Load the ui file
        uic.loadUi("Vsliders.ui", self)

        #define widgets
        self.slider         = self.findChild(QSlider,"slider")
        self.slider_value   = self.findChild(QLabel,"slider_value")

        # Slider properties
        self.slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.slider.setValue(10)
        self.slider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksRight)
        self.slider.setTickInterval(5)
        self.slider.setSingleStep(5)

        # Move the slider
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slide_it)

        #show the App
        self.show()

    def slide_it(self, value):
        self.slider_value.setText(str(value))

#Initialize the app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
UIWindow = UI()
app.exec_()

I understand we connect the only value on the slide_it function. But how do we hook up 2 values for example ?
like : how can i grab the 'int' value of the slider ? and use it to calculate ?
i tried this :
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slide_it)
        self.slider_2.valueChanged.connect(self.slide_it)

        #show the App
        self.show()

    def slide_it(self, value, value2):
        self.slider_value.setText(str(value + value2))

I was expecting it to take slide 1 on value and slider 2 on value2.
But it returns :
TypeError: UI.slide_it() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value2'

insted of
self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slide_it)

i tried
self.slider.value.connect(self.slide_it)

# or 

test = self.slider.value() # as a variable value 

    # for example adding directly both values in my function

    def slide_it(self):
        self.slider_value.setText(str(self.slider.value() + self.slider_2.value() ))


but it turns out those functions cannot be directly used as variable value.
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable

Also .value() doesn't make anything moving. I think it really takes .valueChanged attribute.
i also tried this which is not exactly what i want but it does a result
    def slide_it(self, value):
        self.slider_value.setText(str(value + 2))

This way i get the to added to the initial value, displayed on a label. and yes it works. but this a value i add manually.
i guess the only method i know in that case, are used for one slider value at once.

The self.slider_value.setText(str(self.slider.value() + self.slider_2.value())) attempt is the correct one, the TypeError you report doesn't match your code, and it's probably caused by randomly trying things and forgetting invalid pieces of code somewhere. Note that you must connect the signals of both sliders to the same function (which shouldn't get any argument).

Unrelated: 1. there's no need to "define widgets", as loadUi() automatically creates instance attributes based on their object names (self.slider and self.slider_value already exist); 2. it's good practice to not call self.show() within the __init__, but always do it externally after it returns (UIWindow.show(), in this case); 3. only classes and constants should have capitalized names (prefer something like uiWindow instead of UIWindow); see the official Style Guide for Python Code.

@musicamante oh really for the "define widgets" functions ? i do this related to John Elder's (codemy.com) tutorials. He is always doing this to define widgets
example here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQ4KVj-EVOk&list=PLCC34OHNcOtpmCA8s_dpPMvQLyHbvxocY&index=41
then if there's no need to do this, what self.findChild() is used for ?
and thanks for the other references

@musicamante ok it works. thank you ! i will put a final answer.

First of all, since one of your attempts was actually valid and no proper related [mre] was provided, that makes your post not-reproducible: even by your own admission, the problem was most certainly caused by inappropriate syntax, and such situations are considered off topic on StackOverflow. Then, about the findChild() issue, I have two important suggestions: 1. never trust video tutorials blindly, especially if they come from generic programming channels and are targeted to specific and quite extended modules/frameworks (such as Qt); I've already written a complaint to the codemy »

» channel owners about the many issues in their tutorials (including the superficial usage of findChild(), not to mention the wrong findChile() spelling shown in the video), and I also took similar actions for related channels/videos (I obviously got no reply, and I was even banned from comments); while such sources may be helpful, they should always be considered with awareness. 2. the are rare cases for which findChild() is necessary: one is code completion in an IDE that doesn't or can't provide access to dynamically created objects, the other is for objects created »

» from private Qt classes/functions (for instance, UI elements of QDialog subclasses such as QFileDIalog), which is something normally used at advanced programming level. For the former case, there are possible work-arounds for the uic functions such as loadUi(), but unless you really need that feature, there is absolutely no need for findChild(): just use self.<objectName> right after loadUi(<UI file>, self) to access those objects. And, in case I wasn't clear enough, do not trust such video tutorials so blindly: learning is about understanding, not just following instructions.

yes, i did a few more codes since then, without the findChild() function. Works like charm

ok thanks peoples for help !
for the raised TypeError, probably it was a synthax matter.
it worked that way :
    # Move the slider
    self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slide_it)
    self.slider_2.valueChanged.connect(self.slide_it)

    #show the App
    self.show()

def slide_it(self):
    self.slider_value.setText(str(self.slider.value() + self.slider_2.value()))

